# SPD Editor Issues

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have been using SharePoint designer to work on a page, and in the editor, I apparently hit some combination of  and some other keys that changed my quotation marks (both single and double).  They are now angled and do not work as they should- they are simply characters, rather than quotations.  Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have no idea what this is for, but apparently the combination was `CTRL+SHIFT+'`.  Problem solved.

EDIT: For anyone that comes across this answer looking for help, check the comments below.  It was pointed out to me by @RJ_Cuthbertson that this 'feature' is erroneously called Smart Quotes and appears to be a pain in many sides.

Comment: http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/typographic-tips/smart-quotes

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have no idea why anyone would want those, but at least now I understand what the problem was.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me either, but it's one of those artsy typeset designer sorta things. One of those "Can I get that icon in cornflower blue?" type things.